# Как увеличить размер DomStorage?

Tags: android

Возможно ли увеличить обем localStorage для webview?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895408/how-can-i-increase-the-quota-limit-of-localstorage-in-android-webview

Comment: Ну... это слишком банальный ответ. Разве нет возможности перехватить обращение webview к  domStorage и в место нее обращатся к другой сущности (скажем нативной SQLite).